# $(document).ready(function() getting wrong results when determining <div> heights when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jquery to determine the biggest height of a few div tags that contain text within the same class and resize all the div tags to the same size as the height of the biggest div tag so they are all the same height.
I'm using the following function and the alert I'm testing it with gives me a result of either "100" (correct size) or "80" (incorrect) when the script is run.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 $(document).ready(function()                
  {
      var paddedHeight = 0;
      var maxHeighta = Math.max.apply(null, $("div.txtBoxContent").map(function ()
      {
          return $(this).height();
      }).get());
     paddedHeight = maxHeighta+20;
     $("div.txtBoxContent").css('height', paddedHeight);
     alert(paddedHeight);
  }
);
```

Comment: Does the div have images?

Comment: Provide a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue but could not give me an incorrect value. But if you have control over the css you could just use flex box and set display flex on the container element and it will make all the div heights equal

Comment: When you already know what the correct size is, why don't you just apply this size to the divs?

Comment: Try to get outer height instead of height.

Comment: I solved the problem by using a setTimeout to check the divs for height. It seems the document.ready would sometimes execute before the page was fully loaded and give an inacurate height of the divs I was checking.